Deploy a C# project with SQL Server
I completed building a project and it worked fine with the SQL server connection until I added the .mdf file to the environment and changed the connection statement in app.config.
now after I enter the login info to the log-in form it shows me this error

A connection was successfully established with the server but then an error during login process no process is on the other end of the pipe

The connection string is:
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Cargo System.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;MultiSubnetFailover=True;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=False;

I used the connection string that showed in properties of the database in Visual Studio.
what I tried to solve this:

add Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True; Encrypt=False
Server (Right Click) -> Properties -> Security -> Server Authentication -> SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.
Enforce Password Policy.
Change Login Auditing to none.

I will mention again that the error is showing in the C# program after I moved the database to it, and it didn't appear when I worked with the SQL server connection directly, but I tried many the solutions.

Try to view port restrictions, may be your server(where SQL Server) is filtering connections

Your description is a bit vague. Are you saying that you added the MDF file to he project? If so then you need to use the AttachDbFilename attribute in your connection string in order to attach that file to the specified instance at run time. If that's not what you're talking about, please exp-lain what "I added the database to the environment" and "I move the database to it" actually mean. If you already are using that, why doesn't your question say so?

Best way of debugging is to Use SQL Server Management Studio and connect to the server.  Check if login window shows Windows Credential (Integrated Security = True) or SQL Credentials.  The check log files in explorer under Management.

I just solved the problem simply with check the connection string in the code -that I used it for getting and setting the queries- there was some differences between it and the connection string in app.config, when they matched it worked perfectly.
